# Java - split string with special delimiter

Tags: java, string

I have a String, which I want to split into parts using delimeter }},{". I have tried using:

```
String delims="['}},{\"']+";
String field[]=new String[50];
field=subResult.split(delims);
```

But it is not working :-( do you know, what expression in delims should I use?

Thanks for your replies

Comment: Do you need the double quotes `"` in the delimiter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the delimiter is simply `}},{` then `subResult.split("\\}\\},\\{")` should work

```
String fooo = "asdf}},{bar}},{baz";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fooo.split("\\}\\},\\{")));
```

Answer (score 3):

A `{` is a regex meta-character which marks the beginning of a character class. To match a literal `{` you need to escape it by preceding it with a `\\` as:

```
String delims="}},\\{";
String field[] = subResult.split(delims);
```

You need not escape the `}` in your regex as the regex engine infers that it is a literal `}` as it is not preceded by a opening `{`. That said there is no harm in escaping it.

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/OXaa5)

Answer (score 1):

You should be escaping it.

```
String.split("\\}\\},\\{");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could be making it more complex than you need.

```
String text = "{{aaa}},{\"hello\"}";
String[] field=text.split("\\}\\},\\{\"");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(field));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[}},{\"]");        
// Split input with the pattern
String[] result = p.split(MyTextString);
```